How to transform JSON array to nested structure using Jolt in Apache NiFi?
I'm trying to use Jolt in Apache NiFi to transform my JSON data from the input structure to the desired output structure. Here's my input JSON:
[
  {
    "LocationAvailabilitySync": {
      "TransactionNumber": "31ea1a10-abc4-4aa5-a8c6-6f204903073a",
      "TransactionType": "SyncDetail",
      "CurrentPage": 5,
      "CurrentCount": 15,
      "TotalCount": 9,
      "TotalPages": 9,
      "SyncCount": null,
      "ViewConfigurationName": null
    },
    "ItemId": "5678",
    "LocationId": "0088",
    "Status": "AVAILABLE",
    "ViewName": "ATC_1",
    "ViewId": "05fdb789-a372-4f0e-8e35-9517f3cf02cc",
    "Quantity": 567,
    "TransactionDateTime": "2020-04-29T18:35:56.662",
    "NextAvailabilityDate": null,
    "TotalIncludingSubstituteItems": 567,
    "SubstituteItemsAvailable": false,
    "SubstitutionDetail": null
  },
  {
    "LocationAvailabilitySync": {
      "TransactionNumber": "31ea1a10-abc4-4aa5-a8c6-6f204903073a",
      "TransactionType": "SyncDetail",
      "CurrentPage": 5,
      "CurrentCount": 15,
      "TotalCount": 9,
      "TotalPages": 9,
      "SyncCount": null,
      "ViewConfigurationName": null
    },
    "ItemId": "1234",
    "LocationId": "0088",
    "Status": "AVAILABLE",
    "ViewName": "ATC_1",
    "ViewId": "05fdb789-a372-4f0e-8e35-9517f3cf02cc",
    "Quantity": 567,
    "TransactionDateTime": "2020-04-29T18:35:56.662",
    "NextAvailabilityDate": null,
    "TotalIncludingSubstituteItems": 567,
    "SubstituteItemsAvailable": false,
    "SubstitutionDetail": null
  }
]

And here's the desired output JSON:
{
  "LocationAvailabilitySync": [
    {
      "TransactionNumber": "31ea1a10-abc4-4aa5-a8c6-6f204903073a",
      "TransactionType": "SyncDetail",
      "CurrentPage": 5,
      "CurrentCount": 15,
      "TotalCount": 9,
      "TotalPages": 9,
      "SyncCount": null,
      "ViewConfigurationName": null,
      "LocationAvailabilityResponse": [
        {
          "ItemId": "5678",
          "LocationId": "0088",
          "Status": "AVAILABLE",
          "ViewName": "ATC_SOFKA1",
          "ViewId": "e88130a2-6a07-408b-8bf8-03e3d28cf057",
          "Quantity": 567,
          "TransactionDateTime": "2020-04-29T18:35:56.662",
          "NextAvailabilityDate": null,
          "TotalIncludingSubstituteItems": 567,
          "SubstituteItemsAvailable": false,
          "SubstitutionDetail": null
        },
        {
          "ItemId": "1234",
          "LocationId": "0088",
          "Status": "AVAILABLE",
          "ViewName": "ATC_SOFKA2",
          "ViewId": "e88130a2-6a07-408b-8bf8-03e3d28cf058",
          "Quantity": 567,
          "TransactionDateTime": "2020-04-29T18:35:56.662",
          "NextAvailabilityDate": null,
          "TotalIncludingSubstituteItems": 567,
          "SubstituteItemsAvailable": false,
          "SubstitutionDetail": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I need help with creating the Jolt specification to achieve this transformation. Can anyone provide guidance or an example Jolt spec that can accomplish this?
Thank you!

sYou can use a cardinality spec in order to pick only one component from each array which are formed while combining the attributes nested within "LocationAvailabilitySync" object in the shift spec such as
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "LocationAvailabilitySync": {
          "*": "&1[0].&"
        },
        "*": "LocationAvailabilitySync[0].LocationAvailabilityResponse[&1].&"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE",
          "LocationAvailabilityResponse": "MANY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

